Python operator overloading - chaining '>' does not work as expected
I'm trying to make a class that can keep track of basic join operations between instances of that class. See the minimum reproducible example below
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Literal


class Block():
    jointype_lookup = {'both': '>', 'right': '>>', 'left': '<<'}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.join_stack = [self]
        self.join_stack_types = []

    @classmethod
    def _from_join_opertation(cls, block1: Block, block2: Block, join_type: Literal['left', 'right', 'both']):
        self = cls.__new__(cls)
        self.join_stack = block1.join_stack + block2.join_stack
        self.join_stack_types = block1.join_stack_types + [join_type] + block2.join_stack_types
        return self

    def __gt__(self, other: Block):
        # join both
        return_graph_obj = Block._from_join_opertation(self, other, 'both')
        return return_graph_obj

    def __rshift__(self, other: Block):
        # join right
        return_graph_obj = Block._from_join_opertation(self, other, 'right')
        return return_graph_obj

    def __lshift__(self, other: Block):
        # join left
        return_graph_obj = Block._from_join_opertation(self, other, 'left')
        return return_graph_obj

    def __str__(self):
        command = f"{self.join_stack[0].name}"
        for i, type in enumerate(self.join_stack_types):
            command += f" {self.jointype_lookup[type]} {self.join_stack[i+1].name}"
        return command

command = Block('oxygen') >> Block('hydrogen') >> Block('helium') >> Block('carbon')
print(command)
# output: oxygen >> hydrogen >> helium >> carbon

command = Block('oxygen') << Block('hydrogen') << Block('helium') << Block('carbon')
print(command)
# output: oxygen << hydrogen << helium << carbon

command = Block('oxygen') > Block('hydrogen') > Block('helium') > Block('carbon')
print(command)
# output: helium > carbon

The last example is the problem. I can fix this by surrounding each successive operation in brackets (which is not ideal for my use case), but I'm keen on understanding why the comparison operators seem to work fundamentally differently to the other operators and if there is a way to change their behaviour

Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. Shame there seems no way around it. I will just use alternative operators

Use the raw methods for the join operations, thus allowing chaining or use different symbols for chaining, but ensure they do not conflict with built-in operators.
Example:
# Usage
command1 = Block('oxygen').join_right(Block('hydrogen')).join_right(Block('helium')).join_right(Block('carbon'))


Thanks for your response. Indeed I can just use other operators. I was hoping not to have to switch as the syntax becomes less clear. Thanks anyway

Short Answer
This is due to how python processes chained comparsion, you can briefly see how it works in the following edited code.
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Literal

class Block():
    jointype_lookup = {'both': '>', 'right': '>>', 'left': '<<'}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.join_stack = [self]
        self.join_stack_types = []

    @classmethod
    def _from_join_opertation(cls, block1: Block, block2: Block, join_type: Literal['left', 'right', 'both']):
        self = cls.__new__(cls)
        self.join_stack = block1.join_stack + block2.join_stack
        self.join_stack_types = block1.join_stack_types + [join_type] + block2.join_stack_types
        return self

    def __gt__(self, other: Block):
        return_graph_obj = Block._from_join_opertation(self, other, 'both')
        # ------
        # print the comparsion
        # ------
        print(f"gt comparing: {str(self):>8} > {str(other):>8}, and returned: {str(return_graph_obj)}")
        return return_graph_obj

    def __str__(self):
        command = f"{self.join_stack[0].name}"
        for i, type in enumerate(self.join_stack_types):
            command += f" {self.jointype_lookup[type]} {self.join_stack[i+1].name}"
        return command

print("Result: ", Block('oxygen') > Block('hydrogen') > Block('helium'))

gt comparing:   oxygen > hydrogen, and returned: oxygen > hydrogen
gt comparing: hydrogen >   helium, and returned: hydrogen > helium
Result:  hydrogen > helium

Explaination
Python process chained comparsion one by one, and if the result returned True, in your case, returned an object, which is not a False value, then it ignores it, continue to the next.
Why? well, if you take an example of 5 > 3 > a, python processes 5 > 3 first, this is obviously True, so it skips the result, and continues to 3 > a.
Why again? because if the previous greater comparsion is True, then it won't affect the answer anymore, no matter it's 3.0001 > 3 > a or 10000000 > 3 > a.
You can consider if it carries the previous result, then the chained comparsion of 4 > 3 > 2 would be:

4 > 3 returns True
True > 2 returns False (since True would be interpret as 1)

That's why if you wrap it with (), it process those in the brackets first, returning the result, than continue to the next, without ignoring and skipping.
Work around - 1
I'd suggest to use another symbol for this (try __div__ for /), but if the > sign have special meaning, you can try parsing the expression as a string.
import re

class Block:
    def __init__(self, expression) -> None:
        expression = expression.replace(' ', '') # remove spaces
        self.join_stack = re.sub(r"(\<+|\>+)", ' ', expression).split()
        self.join_stack_types = re.findall(r"(\<+|\>+)", expression)
        print(self.join_stack)
        print(self.join_stack_types)

    def __str__(self):
        command = f"{self.join_stack[0]}"
        for i, _type in enumerate(self.join_stack_types): # 'type' is a keyword, so prevent using it as a var with leading '_'
            command += f" {_type} {self.join_stack[i+1]}"
        return command

print(Block("oxygen >> hydrogen >> helium > carbon"))

Work around - 2
As mentioned by @ahskur, you can use Method Chaining, which is a common syntax in JavaScript.
Block('oxygen') \
  .join_right(Block('hydrogen')) \
  .join_right(Block('helium')) \
  .join_right(Block('carbon'))

